# Generating an unique random number every time a C client runs

Tags: c, random, numbers, client-server, unique

I am trying to code a client/server application in C where each client sends a specific value ( a randomly generated number between 1 to 50) to the server. 
But the problem is that each client sends the same random number to the server.

This is part of the code on the client side:

```
srand(time(NULL));
id=rand()%50 + 1;
```

I do understand that since the seed is set to the same value each time a client runs and probably that's the reason why there is a same random number as well.

Can anyone please suggest a way to rectify this?

Comment: are you calling `srand()` in every thread? If so don't call it once before all of the threads start.

Comment: I am trying to generate the random numbers on the client side . SO everytime a new client is executed the srand function gets executed as well. 

( I just saw that the previous heading of my question was wrong and edited it. Extremely sorry if that confused you)

Comment: Are the clients each their own program? Each program should only call `srand()` once it's meant to see the random number generator you only seed it once (usually during the setup).

Comment: There is one client program and one server program. So in order to say get 4 clients , I execute the client program 4 times using the script.sh file. Each client generates a random number and sends to the server..
The server then creates a new thread for each client and accepts the message sent by the clients

Comment: As long as each clients isn't executed simultaneously at the same second, the seed will be different for each.

Comment: a random number between 1 and 50 isn't exactly an *identifier*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
srand(clock());
```

The `time()` function uses *seconds* precision. This might not be fine grained enough if all 4 clients are executed with almost no interval between them *or* completely in parallel (i.e., all clients run effectively during the same second as returned by `time()`). The `clock()` function provides a better temporal resolution.

Worth noting that C — unlike most language these days ;) — have almost no startup overhead at all (when compared with a runtime managed language, etc). As such, each program starts execution almost immediately after being called by your shell script.

**Alternatives**. Another solution would be to forget about using the time/clock as a seed altogether. Just pass an *unique integer*, as a command line argument, in your script for each one of those 4 instances and use that instead (as seed or client id).

Answer (score 0):

You could for example add the client's id (something to identify each client) to the seed, additionally to the time that you're already using. That way you should get unique random seeds and thus also different random numbers per client.